# setting class of id based on input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, input

```
$(function(){

    if ($('#videoId').val){

    var thisid = $('#videoId').val; 
    $("#videolist li[id$='vid-"+thisid+"]").addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

.

```
<ul id="videolist">
    <li id="vid-28">Option</li>
    <li id="vid-29">Another Option</li>
    <li id="vid-30">Third Option</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qdzn2/5/

I want the li with the id that matches the value of the input to be assigned the 'selected' class.

The code is commented out right now because it's causing an endless loop, but also when I trace my thisid variable it gets an extremely long value that looks like jquery code.. I have 'value' working elsewhere, so I do not know what's causing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need this as well:

```
$(function(){
    $("#vid-" + $('#videoId').val()).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: `#videolist li` is not needed at all it is an ID therefore it should be unique as it is ... no need for the extras

Comment: It could be smart to add this, for instance, when an element with the id `vid-28` can occur on another page too, but outside of the `#videolist` element, in which case you don't want your code to fire.

Comment: I removed the unneeded hierarchy within the selector. Was going to omit it, but didn't want to remove it in case accidentally there was id reusage as pointed out just above.

Comment: re used element should be really classes not IDs therefore you will only need to change the parent id to dismiss the rest, it's bad practice especially for future reference for other developers who'd pull their hair out trying to figure out + how silly that code looks :) just an opinion for being more efficient

Comment: I'm not disputing that IDs are unique - I am stating that I have inherited projects where this hasn't been the case due to bad coding practice. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should call `val()`, not `val`. When omitting the parentheses, you actually refer to the function instead of calling it. Do what you are alerting is the source of the val function. :)

[edit]

Also, you missed a closing single quote around the attribute value in the `vid-` selector. Update fiddle is found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rGbw8/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(function(){

if ($('#videoId').val()){

var thisId = $('#videoId').val();

$("#vid-"+thisId+"").addClass('selected');
}
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qdzn2/16/

Comment: this is silly `($('#videoId').val)` will always return true :)